# How to set custom color in android

Tags: java, android, android-color

This is my *res/values/color.xml*

```xml
<resources>
    <color name="ColorPrimary">#FF5722</color>
</resources>
```

this is *.java* file

```java
Color color = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary); //Error
textView.setTextColor(color);
```

It's giving me an error.
**Required android.graphics.Color. Found int**

How can I handle it?

Comment: which error? Please provide an exception stacktrace

Comment: Did you try to clean your project and build again?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Incompatible types: Required android.graphics.Color. Found int

Comment: Check your context and please provide the error log.

Comment: @BishopBarber it doesn't help

Comment: @DerGolem I have it, but still doesn't work

Comment: @DerGolem I'm doing it on  *RecyclerView.Adapter* and sending a contex into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [getColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)) method returns an int, but you try to store it in a Color object. I suggest you simply do this:

```
textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary))
```

Since [setTextColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)) takes an int in parameters.